# DSX not fully installed

Tags: installation, data-science-experience, dsx-desktop

I installed DSX workstation, MacOS selecting docker native, python 2.7 & 3.5, plus RStudio.

However when I look at installed comoponents I just see:
Docker Native (required)
Notebook: Anaconda (Python 3.5) Uninstall
RStudio: Uninstall

Should 2.7 be listed too? I don't see it as an option either?

Can I add it without a full uninstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only select one option for Jupyter Notebooks; the app only recognized the second option you clicked - Anaconda (Python 3.5). If you meant to install the third option, the settings page should read "Anaconda + Spark (Python 2.7/3.5, Scala, R)". Since you can't have two Jupyter Notebook images, you should uninstall Anaconda (Python 3.5) by clicking the uninstall button that appears next to it, and then install the third option from that same page (the uninstall button will switch to 'install').

Comment: Thanks. I did actually try this the day after and it worked ok... it just wasn't entirely obvious as I'd interpreted each as seperate options.